# Clear pixels with overlapping content

Tags: c++, opengl, gpgpu

I'm rendering a quad-mesh to an off-screen framebuffer in OpenGL with possibly overlapping quads (more fragments into a single framebuffer pixel). All quads lie in the plane y=0.
I would like to know if there is an easy way to set a color (e.g. black) to pixels that have overlapping quads (preferrably without the need of an extra shader pass, using simple OpenGL functionality).

Comment: Pixels do not have "overlapping quads." They have a color, nothing more. You can set pixels to whatever color you want. It's not clear what doing that has to do with "overlapping quads", since again, that's not something pixels store. Can you give some kind of example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the stencil buffer to count the "overdraw" per pixel with something like

```
glClear(GL_STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT)<
glEnable(GL_STENCIL_TEST);
glStencilOp(GL_KEEP, GL_INCR, GL_INCR);
glStencilFunc(GL_ALWAYS, 0, 0xffffff);
```

which would simply clear the stencil buffer to 0 and increase it for every fragment you draw after that (and also for all fragments you generate, but fail the depth test). After you have drawn all quads, you could draw another fullscreen quad with the desired color, but the stencil test set to

```
glStencilFunc(GL_GREATER, 1, 0xffffff);
```

to only affect the pixels with more than one quad.
This still requires some kind of "extra pass", but the stencil test is quite efficient.

Comment: I was exactly looking for a solution like this, thank you! I had to change GL_GREATER to GL_LESS to have the fragments with stencil > 1 pass the test and overwrite the color.

Comment: Hmm, I don't see how this can work with GL_LESS, but whatever.

Comment: http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glStencilFunc.xml says:

GL_LESS
Passes if ( ref & mask ) < ( stencil & mask ).

Comment: For pixels with more than one fragment written into the stencil value will be more than 1. The test accepts fragments if ref<stencil (which is 1<stencil because ref=1) and thus the desired color is written into the framebuffer only for pixels with overlapping content.

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right. I got myself confused by some simple inequality, sorry.